# Apache/Varnish/PHP: Just to confirm, is it possible to automatically update $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to have the real client's IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, varnish

I just cannot seem to get the real client IP to show in PHP's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  It shows in $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'], but the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] always points to the Varnish service IP.

I've played around with just about every Varnish vcl suggestion I could find.  I've installed Apache module mod_rpaf.  But I still cannot get $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to reflect the client's real IP...

So my question is, ***is this even possible***?  Does everyone who uses Varnish have to do something like this for all PHP applications?:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Or am I simply not configuring it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_extract_forwarded is most supported, stable and available module for this.
Included in all major distributions.

http://www.openinfo.co.uk/apache/

Comment: Interesting.  You mention its in all major distributions, but I cannot seem to find it in my Ubuntu 12.04 repository:  apt-cache search apache2-mod  Doesn't show it.  Does this mean I'd need to download the source and compile it for my host?

Comment: Another question, when I compile that module using apxs2 -iac and restart Apache I get this error: apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/extract_forwarded.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_extract_forwarded.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_extract_forwarded.so: undefined symbol: proxy_hook_scheme_handler
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

Comment: Seems like your distro doesn't include correct headers and library combination. Search for binaries in repos. apt-cache search extract

Comment: Also, I've used mod_realip2 for some time, but I like mod_extract_forwarded more for reasons described before.

Comment: @Gavin or anyone else having the undefined symbol: proxy_hook_scheme_handler error, you need to enable mod_proxy too.  Uncomment the line in httpd.conf LoadModule proxy_module lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, use mod_extract_forwarded.

If you get the following error when reloading the apache configuration:

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_extract_forwarded.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_extract_forwarded.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_extract_forwarded.so: undefined symbol: proxy_hook_scheme_handler
```

Just load the mod_proxy module **before** mod_extract_forwarded. Works fine on CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) which can be configured to 'fix' this for you

> It changes the remote address of the client visible to other Apache modules when two conditions are satisfied...

Comment: I have actually been using mod_rpaf.  I am getting the correct client IP in $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'], just not in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].  Is this normal, or am I messing something up?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error
"undefined symbol: proxy_hook_scheme_handler Action 'configtest' failed. "

I ran into the same issue and t this web page, but no mention of a solution on the web.
The possible solutions are inside the 'INSTALL' of the package!

> If the Apache instance you are adding mod_extract_forwarded to will
>   not have mod_proxy and proxy_http loaded then you will get an error
>   when mod_extract_forwarded is loaded. In that case edit
>   mod_extract_forwarded.c and comment out the #define for
>   USING_proxy_http_module or change it to an an #undef. If you
>   subsequently run Apache with proxy_http do not forget to reinstate the #define;
>   failure to do so will mean that any X-Fowarded-For header inserted by proxy_http will use the spoofed IP number in error.

So basically:either enable 'mod_proxy and proxy_http' OR comment out the 'USING_proxy_http_module' define in the c file and rebuild.
The latter worked for me, I apparently applied the first solution on an earlier server setup (and I forgot about it).

[Edit:]
Install 'mod_proxy' with
   apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html

Answer (score 0):

I personally make use of the [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive in php.ini

Just create a PHP script like so:

```
<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

and then edit your php.ini to execute the script before any other script.