# nginx varnish nginx php-fpm: real ip for php's _SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, varnish

This is specific question.

A Nginx server (call it N1) listens on :80 and forwards to varnish with proxy_pass
Varnish listens on 127.0.0.1:6081 and forwards to Nginx (N2) on 8080.
N2 talks to the php-fpm socket.

N1<>V<>N2<>P

N1:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_pass http://varnish/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

currently

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'

desired

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'The real remote addr'

Comment: Similar question : http://serverfault.com/questions/425509/apache-varnish-php-just-to-confirm-is-it-possible-to-automatically-update-se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specific answer. ;)

You could add a x-forwarded-for in N1, let that pass through varnish and N2 to fastcgi:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then in fastcgi params:

```
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: There's a common trick with a module called "RealIpHeader" or something, and it also allows rewriting of the REMOTE_ADDR, but I figure it's more clean using the x-forwarded-for.

Comment: however $http_x_forwarded_for is an array. I'm not sure of the type of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. So when passing through 2 proxies, like in this case there will be 2 IPs in $_SERVER['X-FORWARDED-FOR']. Your answer helped me because my final solution was fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip; since I set X-Real-IP in N1.

Comment: Don't do this. as @dalu mentioned, X-Forwarded-For might have comma-separated IPs, and this will lead to incorrect headers. The right way to do it using real_ip nginx module: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html